# .change() call for @html.dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following Dropdownlist in my Razor code, and I wish to call a method when the value in the Dropdown list is selected. But the function is not being called.

```
//In view
@Html.DropDownList("Taglist",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Taglist, new { @class="taglist" })
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".taglist").change(function () {
    alert("Success");
});
</script>

//In Controller
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Taglist = new SelectList(_context.Tag_Tree_Def, "ID", "NAME");
        return View();
    }
```

Can anyone help me making this thing work. I know its a minor thing, but I can not just see it. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Not sure, you may need event delegation. Try `$(document).on('change', '.taglist', function() {`

Comment: Try wrap your event under document ready. `$(function(){$(".taglist").change(function ()...});`

Comment: Could you post the rendered output?  Is the script tag above or below your jquery include.. and is the script after the control?  If your script is in the head, the element on the page doesn't exist when your js is run.

Comment: @PrithviDammalapati -- No problem, I posted a quick answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears you need event delegation, change your `change()` handler to the following:

```
$(document).on('change', '.taglist', function() {
```